# spring boot binding app properties for nested class

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I'm trying to bind app properties to the below class with a nested properties but it's not working as I get a NPE for the nested properties. Basically the two nested classes share the same props so wanted to extract it to its own class.

I want to access the props like `helloPropsInstance.foo.getA()` is this possible? i'm using lombok too.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="hello")
@ConstructorBinding
@Getter
@Setter
public class HelloProps {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    public static class Foo extends Base {}

    public static class Bar extends Base {}

    public static class Base {
        private String a; // works fine if I copy these props to Foo and Bar
        private String b;
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove `static` modifier.

Comment: Don't remove `static`, but do tell us where exactly you get the NPE (on `foo`, or on `foo.a`), and please confirm you have getters/setters _on `Base`_ (you only showed them on the top-level class).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- the npe is on foo. I do have getters and setters on Base

Comment: If you don't add any new properties, is there a reason not to say simply `Base foo = new Base()`?

Comment: the goal was to add some additional props to each classs

Comment: Instance or class variables like `foo` and `bar` are reference types and are per default `null` when you initialize `new HelloProps()`. So what do you expect when calling `helloPropsInstance.getFoo().getA()`? BANG!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when we load the properties, they are considered `CONSTANT` unless the application is restarted. In that case, the properties can be treated as `public final` variables without the need of `getters` and `setters` and initialized through constructor.
In your case, if the properties are `hello.foo.a`, `hello.bar.a` etc., then you can do the following:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="hello")
@ConstructorBinding
public class HelloProps {
    public final Base foo;
    public final Base bar;

    public HelloProps(Base foo, Base bar) {
        this.foo=foo;
        this.bar=bar;
    }

    @ConstructorBinding    
    public static class Base {
        public final String a; 
        public final String b;

        public Base(String a, String b) {
            this.a=a;
            this.b=b;
        }     
    }
}
```

With this, all you properties will be accessible as `helloProps.foo.a helloProps.foo.b` with autowiring and you must have already used `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`
This is just Vanilla Java code, but for Lombok, you can use `RequiredArgsConstructor`. Didn't test it though.
Also, since you have not mentioned any other properties of `Foo` and `Bar`, I just used `Base` class. But I don't think, extending it would be any issue since variables are public final.